# Oracle to MSSQL migration error 'The table xxx doesnot exist in target'

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration

I am trying to convert and migrate an Oracle schema to MSSQL server. At the last step, migrating data, I get the error message:

> The table [MYDATABASE].[MYSCHEMA].MYTABLE] doesnot exist in target. You must first convert the table then load it into the database.

This error message appears for each table in my schema.

Can someone explain what is happening and what I need to do to get past this?

Comment: Hard to say without more detail of your conversion process, but it sounds like the tables either aren't getting created, are getting created in the wrong database, or are getting created in the wrong schema.

Comment: Are you tried to migrate the data before doing the ‘synchronize with the database’ operation?

Comment: I did : convert oracle schema, synchronize with database ,migrate data. I did notice in the log file the following entry: Error: Collector] [19012/6] [2018-09-24 09:16:07]: An error occurred when trying to load server edition and server cores count.
[Error: Collector] [19012/6] [2018-09-24 09:16:07]: Exception: ORA-00904: "VL"."CPU_CORE_COUNT_CURRENT": invalid identifier

 site: Void CheckError(System.Data.OracleClient.OciErrorHandle, Int32)
 source: System.Data.OracleClient

Answer (score 13):

Are you tries to migrate the data before doing the ‘synchronize with the database’ operation?

If Yes,

> This error message generally occurs when the target table doesn’t
>   exist on SQL server database. After `converting schema`, you need to
>   `synchronize the table with the database before migrating the data`.
>
> To do this you `right click` on the `SQL Server database` in `Metadata
>   explorer` and click `“Synchronize with database”` menu.

Note: **Table structure will not be created in the SQL server database until you synchronize.**

Comment: this is answer and step to follow in SSMA

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWERS**

**Issues :- Errors: Error occurred while inserting table information into Data Migration Auxiliary table. Reason: Invalid object name 'at17090-fortify17090db-dev.o2ss.MSSsmaDmTables'.

if we don't have admin access then only we have to follow below steps

solution :- The user doesn't have access privileges and Database-level roles to Fixed the issue assign the below Database roles to user:

```
db_datawriter

db_accessadmin
```

command :`alter role db_accessadmin(role name) add member svc_fortify_dev(user/schema name)`

Note:-  for this we need admin access , once provide the Database role then login to SSMA tool and do the Data Migration